# Difference between delay and pushTimeout(), popTimeout() in UIAutomation iOS

Tags: ios, delay, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

What is the difference between

```
app.delay(20);
tableViewCell.waitForInvalid();
```

and

```
app.pushTimeout(20);
tableViewCell.waitForInvalid();
UIATarget.localTarget().popTimeout();
```

In the second case, in case if the cell becomes invalid in say 2secs, then will it still wait for 18secs and then continue or just continue after 2secs ? In the first case, it is waiting until 20secs.

Comment: Use NSLog to check for yourself

Answer (score 0):

No, the second case is preferred because it will wait *up to* 20 seconds for the cell to become invalid. The first case, the script will delay for 20 seconds regardless. Pushing a new timeout changes the system wide timeout when waiting for elements to change on the screen. Pushing and popping as your scripts needs change is a very effective way to manage the different amounts of time you *might* need to wait for the script to verify the behavior you want.